# Using autoinstall storage sizing-policy all, does not work

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, storage, preseed, autoinstall

I'm preparing an `Ubuntu 22.04` iso. I want the default `lvm` size to be `all`, and not `scaled` as Ubuntu's default https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference.

> sizing-policy
> The lvm layout will, by default, attempt to leave room for snapshots and further expansion. A sizing-policy key may be supplied to control this behavior.
> type: string (enumeration)
> default: scaled

For that I tried both:

```
  storage:
    sizing-policy: all
```

And

```
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
```

Nothing seems to work.
The default page I get is:
[image]

I should always edit this part manually to use the whole size.
[image]

Is there a way to make the default `all` ?
Thanks

Note, I also tried using, on `ubuntu 22.04` and `23.10`:

```
  refresh-installer:
    update: true
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
```

Still, did not work.
BTW, I do use the below for making disk part interactive:

```
  interactive-sections:
    - storage
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [the source code](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/b2441fd91dd5978b3c917cc6a9f324cc8883f77d/subiquity/server/controllers/filesystem.py#L1373) it looks like the correct format should be

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
```

However, [the sizing-policy feature](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/commit/a67ce9b8cdb790ea91a8c0a87273f4b8989d8811) was only committed `Apr 3, 2023`.  This feature was included in *subiquity* version [23.04.2](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/releases/tag/23.04.2) (released `Apr 20, 2023`).  This may be newer than the version of *subiquity* on your iso image.

**Note**: The version of *subiquity* is independent of the version of Ubuntu despite the similar naming schemes.  This does not mean you need Ubuntu 23.04.2.

I tested various Ubuntu 22.04 iso images.  The release `ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` includes *subiquity* `23.08.1` and you can use the `sizing-policy` setting.  I tested my snippet above successfully with this iso image.

If you are using an iso image with an older version of *subiquity* then you can try to update *subiquity* as part of the autoinstall.  This may allow you to use the feature.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  refresh-installer:
    update: true
```

**update**

I tested the following autoinstall snippet with the 22.04.3 image (*subiquity* `23.08.1`).

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  interactive-sections:
    - storage
  storage:
    layout:
      name: lvm
      sizing-policy: all
```

The installer GUI does default to a sizing policy of `scaled`.  I confirmed the installer log `/var/log/installer/subiquity-server-debug.log` included

```
DEBUG subiquity.server.server:470 apply_autoinstall_config: skipping Filesystem as interactive
...
DEBUG subiquity.server.controllers.filesystem:303 lv_size 41309700096 for SizingPolicy.SCALED
```

Reviewing [the subiquity code](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/7ce11afd57ba05e681c474a532f69d616d42bd84/subiquity/server/server.py#L471) seems to confirm that the autoinstall configuration is **not** applied to any interactive section.  This means that the autoinstall file can **not** be used to set the default values of the GUI.

You can submit a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity) or look to see if one already exists.

Comment: Thank you.
I've tried with both `Ubuntu 22.04` and `23.10`. Couldn't make it work :/.

Comment: @hudac, the answerer emphasized "update subiquity as part of the autoinstall". If that's not possible, wait "until version 23.10.1" or 24.04.

Comment: That's what I did, using `refresh-installer: update: true`.

Comment: @hudac I've updated the notes based on testing.  The feature was released earlier than I thought and I added a note to hopefully clear up confusion around the version.

Comment: @AndrewLowther, thank you.
Actually I've tested with `ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` and ubuntu `23.10` but I couldn't make it work. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. I'm using `interactive-sections: - storage` because I want the user to configure the disks. I just want the default size would be `all`.

Comment: @hudac I tested with interactive-sections and saw the same results.  I updated the answer with notes from the test.

Comment: @AndrewLowther thank you. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/2055070